My ISP doesn't let me change my DNS to OpenDNS, can I buy another router to override it?
My ISP provided me with a wireless router, but it doesn't allow me to change the DNS settings on it, somehow my ISP only works if I connect to their DNS.
Is there a way to get around this?
Can I buy another wireless router and set the DNS on that, and connect that using a cable to my ISP's router?

Have you tried this? Have you tried changing DNS settings on one of your devices to check if it works? That will be the way to tell whether that will work. What research have you done regarding this and what have you tried so far?

You can definitely install a router inline behind your ISP router, and configure it as you wish, but you should first verify that it will work to solve your DNS issue before making that investment, by testing with a single machine as music2myear suggests. ISPs can do shady stuff when there is a profit motive, so absent encryption, you can't guarantee that they won't mess with your traffic

Can you write in comment who the ISP is? We could look them up and find out what restrictions if any they put in place.

@music2myear yes when I changed the DNS my internet doesn't work, and the provider also says explicitly they will not allow it to be changed.

See if you have the option to do DNS over HTTPS. That should not be able to be intercepted, but it also means what when you select a router to implement this, you'll need to choose one that offers DNS over HTTPS as a feature. I would guess not every consumer-grade router offers this.

Uh?
You can always set the DNS manually on the computer itself. You don't have to use the DNS advertised by the router (the ISP router or your own).
However this may not always work: Some ISP's actively block OpenDns/GoogleDNS/CloudFlare etc, so you are forced to use their own DNS, so they can monitor what sites you are visiting.
They usually do that either because they have to because of government policy. Or because they want to earn extra money by selling that info to data-brokers and/or advertizing companies.

other ISPs may rewrite the destination on DNS traffic to go to a server of their choice (and may even rewrite the response so that it appears to come from the DNS server you meant to contact in the first place. The best way to deal with that is either a VPN, or DNS over HTTPs (DoH) / DNS over TLS (DoT). https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-over-tls/

i want it done globally for the house
